# How would an animal with legs longer than its torso perform?

Tags: bio-mechanics, locomotion

The horror game Poppy Playtime features a monster called Catnap. Simply put, the creature has legs far longer than its torso, like a giraffe but minus the long neck (its based on a cat).

The game shows Catnap as being quite agile. However, looking at him I wonder if something with that sort of bodyplan could really move all that well. I know giraffes can't run very fast, though given that Catnap doesn't have an overly long neck, I don't think that would be a great real-world analogue.

The game mainly shows him walking around on all fours, even though he is shown standing up straight in one brief scene. In one of the few scenes where you can see him running, he seems to be using a galloping motion. He's also shown being able to climb rather adeptly, and even fit into rather small spaces.

Keep in mind, monsters like Catnap in the game aren't entirely biological. The game doesn't make it clear how much of the is organic and how much is mechanical. Some of the monsters clearly has impossible body plans, like giant heads connected to the body by extremely thin necks, but somehow still able to swallow humans whole. Seriously. Also, the monsters are supposed to be humans transplanted into giant toys. Given this, its highly doubtful that Catnap's overly long limbs are entirely organic, though it does appear to have an analogue for a skeleton in it.

Its obvious that the devs are more designing the monsters to look creepy than anything else. Catnap though really makes me scratch my head; would he really be as agile as he's shown in the game with such cartoonishly long limbs? At least with similar creature the arms are clearly more tentacle-like, but his limbs aren't shown as such. He does actually appear to have elbow and knee joints. His limbs also stay staight most of the time, implying that he does have actual bones or some similar in his limbs. Point I'm making is regardless of how much of him is actually organic, it would probably be safe to treat this question as if he really was.

So, how would an animal perform with a bodyplan like that? Would a giraffe be more agile if it didn't have that overly long neck? That's basically what catnap is (minus the fact that he also doesn't have hooves, being a cat and all). Even without a neck though he's still rather towering. Its hard to get a concept of scale, but based on another toy whose measurement is given, he probably stands around 20 feet at the head when standing upright, just to give you an idea of his scale. Even on all fours, he towers over the player. His back almost touches the ceiling in some interior areas, though he's still shown walking on all fours even in open areas. The game even starts with him carrying the player in his mouth, rather than his arms. Perhaps his overly long limbs just make it too hard for him to stay standing upright? He never does walk standing upright.

Comment: You might get a better reception for hypothetical questions if you asked this on our [worldbuilding.se] site. It's for helping writers/artists/game-designers create their world - seems the sort of thing you have here that you need help with. Be sure to take their tour, read their help centre etc. before posting. ... Ahh, seems you're a member already.

Comment: Your actual question about mechanics is a good one for Biology SE. However, folks here don't like a lot of background or "what got me thinking about this is..." material, thus the down votes and currently 2 close votes. You can improve the reception of your question here by removing most of that stuff, which would be perfectly fine in a different SE site like Worldbuilding. Going from one site to another is like going from one country to another; new customs, traditions, and behaviors that offend the locals. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: creatures with such morphology and features** (except for hunting humans and climbing very well) **already exist, and yes, it's the Giraffes.**

You see:

- Giraffes are actually quite fast, they can run as fast as [35 mph](https://www.dosomething.org/us/facts/11-facts-about-giraffes) (which equals about 56 km/h), which is about the speed of zebras, which also reach speeds [up to 35 mph](https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/animals/zebra). Of course there are substantially faster animals, wild horses for example clock in at up to [54 mph](https://www.strathornfarm.co.uk/characteristics/how-fast-can-a-horse-run), however this is little surprising, as wild horses are so well adapted to running humans domesticated them for transportation.
- Funnily enough, [short-necked giraffes even exist](https://artwolfe.com/2021/04/01/wildlifewednesday-short-necked-giraffes-from-wakanda-africa/) (and still have long legs despite having a short neck, as you can see [here](https://artwolfe.com/2021/04/01/wildlifewednesday-short-necked-giraffes-from-wakanda-africa/)), and given that normal giraffes are already quite fast, it seems reasonable to assume that the neck does not hinder the giraffes while running and the short-necked ones are about as fast as their long-necked counterparts.
- Interestingly, [giraffes can even climb hills to some extent](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=10154747856735930), even tough they're not good climbers.

So actually, (short-necked) Giraffes probably already possess most of the features of Catnap, except for the good climbing skills and hunting people.

Comment: To be clear, catnap isn't 'mine'. Its a character in a horror game franchise. I didn't make him and I don't own him.

Comment: Of course, I didn't consider that this phrasing could be understood that way. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: There's also the giraffe relative, Okapi. Their legs aren't so long, but about the same as the torso.

Comment: Those images look photoshopped to me. Also, when I was little, I saw a tv program showing humans competing against animals (seriously). One of the segments had a human race a giraffe. The human beat the giraffe by a mile. He was beat by a zebra (obviously). Given that humans could only run up to 20~25 mph (this was a full decade before Usain Bolt just so we know), that giraffe clearly wasn't running at 35 mph. It was probably running at about half the speed of the human. I call bs on all this post.

Comment: Oh, and looking it up, I found that very clip! If a giraffe can run at over 30 mph, then how do you explain this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5QwYJoLUfE

Comment: The giraffe has not much of a reason to run at top speed. If it was chased by a predatory animal, it would probably go much faster.

Comment: See also maned wolves.

Comment: Kinda are similar to the Catnap described and is actually predatory. Didn't know such a thing exists, cool.